# How to detect zoom action in the WebBrowser in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I have a windows phone 8 application that uses a WebBrowser control to load a static image and show it to the user.

The larger problem I want to solve is that I want the WebBrowser control to resize to the size of the image so that for small images, the browser control and the image are centered on the page.

I have managed the first part, upon initial loading I get the size and adjust the size of the WebBrowser.

The problem is that once the user uses pinching and tapping gestures, the size of the image changes and it is no longer centered.

How can I detect such events within the WebBrowser?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

What is the need for using WebBrowser to show static image content?
You can use Image Control anyway?

Also have you tried to disable ZoomMode for the ScrollViewer for your Browser?